# Wiko UFeel phone won't restart after logo screen

Tags: internal-storage, backup, adoptable-storage, system-freeze

Recently my Wiko UFeel (using Marshmallow Android) restarted automatically and won't pass from the UFeel logo image. I know I problaby have to do a factory reset, however I need to backup some files to my computer, both from the phone and the SD Card which, unfortunately, is mounted as internal storage, meaning I can't plug it to a card reader or any other Wiko device to copy the files. What I'd like to know, please, is:

1) If I execute the factory reset with the SD card in my device, will the data also be erased or just the data from the internal storage (or both) ?

2) If I execute the factory reset without the SD card in my device, will I be able to use it as is after the phone is reset or will I need to format it ?

3) Is there any way for me to plug the phone to a computer so I can backup the files ?

4) Is there any way I can backup the SD card through some other means ? I  tried ADB but it doesn't recognize my device.

Thank you very much

Comment: You should flash a custom recovery, such as TWRP, then boot to recovery and copy your data

Comment: 1: probably yes, as it's formatted as internal storage. 2: definitely not, as your encryption key is lost after a factory reset. 3: if you've got the encryption key extracted, yes – see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info). 4: maybe, if you have a custom recovery installed.

Comment: @esQmo_ not necessarily installed (correcting myself along); booting into one (`fastboot boot recovery.img`) should suffice. But that requires the bootloader to be unlocked. If that has not already been done beforehand, it will most likely trigger a factory reset, rendering the action useless for the current situation.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that model has a locked bootloader

Answer (score 0):

1. As you formatted the card as internal storage, it will most likely be formatted at a factory reset (as it represents internal storage). Even if it wouldn't, you no longer were able to access it, as the encryption key will be lost after a factory reset.
2. definitely not, as your encryption key is lost after a factory reset (see previous point).
3. if you've got the encryption key extracted (which requires [root-access](/questions/tagged/root-access)), yes – see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info).
4. maybe, if you have a custom recovery installed or can boot into one (`fastboot boot recovery.img`). But that would require the device's bootloader to be unlocked. If you haven't done so already, the unlock process usually implicitly performs a factory reset / data-wipe itself; so this approach only works if the bootloader already had been unlocked before (see: [bootloader-lock](/questions/tagged/bootloader-lock)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. My main priority is to salvage the SD card content, if I can. Is there a way to verify if the bootloader is unlocked with my phone this way ?

Comment: Yes. When you boot into [tag:fastboot] mode, there should be a command to list the status (something like `fastboot oem device-info` or `fastboot oem INFOlock`; `fastboot oem ?` should give you available commands for that). You can check our [fastboot tag-wiki](/tags/fastboot/info) for additional resources, as well as the questions using that tag.